# Fixing this SQL statement?

Tags: sql

I would like to know what is wrong with this SQL statement ?

```
   select *
    from
          select * from Actors where Actors.Name = "John Twain"
    inner join 
          ActorRoles  on   Actors.ActorID = ActorRoles.ActorID
    inner join
          Movies  on       ActorRoles.MovieID=Movies.MovieID
```

Comment: Probably need ()'s around the inner select statement.  But this is a poorly worded question.

Comment: Wish i knew the reason for the down vote ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 select *
    from
          (select * from Actors where Actors.Name = "John Twain") AS Actors
    inner join 
          ActorRoles  on   Actors.ActorID = ActorRoles.ActorID
    inner join
          Movies  on       ActorRoles.MovieID=Movies.MovieID
```

A sub query like this needs ( ) and a table alias for the "new" result table.

But this is better:

```
select *
    from Actors 
    inner join 
          ActorRoles  on   Actors.ActorID = ActorRoles.ActorID
    inner join
          Movies  on       ActorRoles.MovieID=Movies.MovieID 
where Actors.Name = "John Twain"
```

Comment: Marked as answer thanks

Comment: @Rajeshwar No problem. But it seems you did not mark it as answer, but maybe just upvoted it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify?

```
SELECT *
FROM Actors
INNER JOIN ActorRoles ON Actors.ActorID = ActorRoles.ActorID
INNER JOIN Movies ON ActorRoles.MovieID = Movies.MovieID
WHERE Actors.NAME = "John Twain"
```